# Using Java Constructor.newInstance(args) , why the "wrong number of args" error?

Tags: java, class, instance

Why does this fail with the error :

```
Args are: -normi -nosplash
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong 
     number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
    .newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
    .newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl
    .newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at TSStack.main(TSStack.java:14)
```

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Args are: " + args[0]+ " " + args[1] );
        try {
            Constructor<Site> c = Site.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
            c.setAccessible(true); // use reflection to get access to  
                                      //this private constructor
            c.newInstance( (Object[])args );
          } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
          } catch (NoSuchMethodException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
          } catch (InstantiationException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IllegalAccessException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
          }     
}
```

Comment: Cute - you tried to catch a whole bunch of exceptions but still ended up missing this one anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Site.class.getDeclaredConstructor()` will return you default constructor with no arguments, so you must pass it an empty array of arguments which is not the case in your example (otherwise you would fail on the first line with `System.out.println()`).

Comment: The Constructor in question should be capable of taking a variable number of arguments and so why wont it allow me to pass a full argument list?  This is a mystery to me.

Comment: @djangofan- You should probably try to get a constructor that takes a `String[]` as an argument, then; see my post for how to do this.

Comment: @djangofan It does take variable number of arguments, which is 0 in your case. If you have a constructor that takes `String[]`, that's the one you should be looking for, not empty argument one.

Answer (score 4):

When you have this line:

```
Site.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
```

You are getting back a constructor for the `Site` class that takes in no arguments, since `getDeclaredConstructor` is a variadic function that takes in as arguments a list of `Class<?>` objects describing the argument types.  Since you didn't list anything, you're getting back a nullary constructor.

However, you then try creating the object by calling

```
c.newInstance( (Object[])args );
```

This tries passing in `args` as arguments.  Unless `args` is empty, this will cause a problem, since you explicitly asked for a no-argument constructor.

**EDIT**: Since the constructor you're looking for (based on your above comment) wants to take in a variable number of `String`s as an argument, you want to look for a constructor that (I believe) takes in an array of `String`s as its argument, since internally variadic functions are implemented using arrays.  You could do this as follows:

```
Constructor<Site> c = Site.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String[].class);
c.setAccessible(true); // use reflection to get access to this private constructor
c.newInstance( (Object[])args );
```

More importantly though, why are you using reflection at all?  It's faster, cleaner, and safer just to write

```
new Site(args);
```

This allows Java to statically verify the safety of your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cant call "new Site(args) because the only constructor is private, and it taks zero args.

Comment: @djangofan- Out of curiosity, then, why are you trying to pass an array of arguments to it?